# Can the Nikon WU-1a wifi adapter work with an iPhone 6?

Tags: troubleshooting, wifi, nikon-d5200

My WU-1a keeps disconnecting. I have a Nikon D5200. I can't find any solutions to this. I am thinking of returning the device since it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning on airplane mode. That is what many users recommend via reviews in the App Store.

Comment: Using it on airplane mode also worked for me.